# ¿Cuál es el origen de "guay"?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, coloquialismos, españa

En España, desde hace algunos decenios, decimos que algo o alguien es *guay* para significar que tiene un cúmulo de cualidades positivas, normalmente frescas, alegres, divertidas, simpáticas... El uso se ha extendido de tal forma que ya para decir *ok* o *vale* en alguna situación positiva, muchas veces decimos *guay*. Así lo recoge el DLE en su segunda acepción, inlcuida en la edición de 2001:

> [**guay<sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JmihBh3%7CJmj5DLi)
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Esp. Muy bueno, estupendo.
> 2. adv. coloq. Esp. Muy bien.

Ahora bien, el uso de *guay* con esta acepción es relativamente reciente. De hecho, antes tenía un significado totalmente contrario, como indica la primera acepción en el DRAE:

> [**guay<sup>1</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JmihBh3%7CJmj5DLi)
>
> Del gót. wái, y este voz onomat., imit. del lamento; cf. ár. hisp. wáy.
>
> 1. interj. desus. poét. ay.
>
> tener alguien muchos guayes
>
> 1. loc. verb. desus. Padecer grandes achaques o muchos contratiempos de la fortuna

Hay muchas teorías respecto a su origen:

- Que viene de [Marruecos](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?guay)
- Que se trata de un [autoantónimo](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/05/11/articulo/1526047528_834375.html)
- Que viene de *gay*, de la zarzuela o de *YMCA* u otras [en este foro](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=44826)

Pero no he podido encontrar ninguna clara. Y lo más fascinante del caso es que somos coetáneos a su aparición, la hemos visto nacer pero no sabemos de dónde viene. ¿Quizás alguno de vosotros pueda arrojar algo de luz?

Comment: Pues tal y como explica el artículo de El País que mencionas (el de autoantónimo) la palabra tiene muchos años. En el CORPUS encuentro entradas de 1427 por ejemplo: _"En este lugar, o, muy buen padre mío, ya cansado me desamparas, [Anterior]guay[Siguiente], de tanctos librado peligros (...)"_.

Comment: @fedorqui exacto, pero siempre con la acepción primera del DRAE; una expresión usual era 'guay de mí como 'desdichado de mí; el misterio es la aparición de guay como se usa hoy en dia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente, la palabra *guay* es realmente antigua, y se usaba de forma muy parecida al actual *ay*:

> *Creo que los árvoles otro año [non] levarán fruta por tu cabsa, porque siendo comedera de carne comes fruta. Et si así ha de pasar, ¡guay de las frutas et de los árvoles et de las bestias salvajes que las comen, que priado pereçerán!*
>
> Anónimo, "Calila e Dimna", 1251 (España).

Su uso desde el siglo XIII hasta el siglo XX no sufrió cambio alguno:

> *Pues cuando los ciegos guían, aunque sea para adelante, ¡guay de los que lo siguen!*
>
> Jesús Alviz Arroyo, "Un solo son en la danza", 1982 (España).

Y, sin embargo, fue en la década de 1980 cuando empezaron a aparecer los primeros usos de *guay* con su sentido actual, significado que prácticamente llegó para quedarse y nunca más se supo del otro. El más antiguo que he encontrado es este:

> *España no es Hawai —qué guay— para los cantantes que quieren vender discos, pero se van defendiendo.*
>
> ABC (Madrid). 26/09/1983, página 87.

Efectivamente, fue sobre esas fechas que empezaron a darse los registros escritos de la palabra, aunque debió de usarse en el habla coloquial desde un tiempo antes. Me resulta muy curiosa la [gráfica de uso](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guay&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cguay%3B%2Cc0) de la palabra que da Ngram:

[image: Guay]

Se aprecia un ascenso hacia 1975, para luego caer en su uso conforme el nuevo significado se abría paso. Al ser este nuevo significado más coloquial, el porcentaje cayó hasta que en 1998 parece que empezó a repuntar, imagino que por haberse ya establecido completamente su uso a todos los niveles.

Ahora bien, ¿por qué este cambio de significado de la palabra? Pues me temo que eso va a ser difícil de responder. Cuanto más moderna es la palabra, más difícil es rastrear su origen debido al volumen de fuentes disponibles. Posibles teorías:

- Que sea un autoantónimo. No es descabellado, hay veces que la palabra *guay* se ha usado sola como interjección, similar a *¡ay!*, lo cual se puede malinterpretar si el contexto no queda claro y el lector no conoce la existencia de esa palabra. También pudo haber sido a propósito. Existe una novela de 1940 titulada *El Chiplichandle. Acción picaresca* que incluye un personaje que es un perro llamado *Guay*, que es realmente un perro guay:

  > *Nadie supo de dónde trajo aquel perro. Era un perro de caza, ya viejo, con ojos grandes y dulces. Floreció al costado de Isidro, así de improviso, un atardecer. Todos los chiquillos le rodearon y se pusieron a mirarle con respeto.
  >
  >   —¿Cómo se llama?
  >
  >   —"Guay".
  >
  >   —¿Muerde?
  >
  >   —No; no tengáis miedo, no muerde.
  >
  >   Le agarraron de las orejas y le tiraron de la cola.
  >
  >   Uno más atrevido intentó abrirle la boca.
  >
  >   "Guay" se dejó hacer, mansurrón.*
  >
  > Juan Antonio de Zunzunegui, "El Chiplichandle. Acción picaresca", 1940 (España).
- Que proceda del árabe. Sí que es cierto que existe una palabra árabe, كويس (*kuayis*, que se traduce como "bien") cuya pronunciación es similar, y que si pasó primero por Andalucía es más que seguro que perdió la *-s* final, pasando en el habla por *kuayi* o *kuay* y de ahí a *guay*. Sin embargo, no encuentro nada registrado al respecto. Se dice que *guay* denotaba en el ámbito de la droga al hachís de buena calidad, en contraposición al *jaravaca* (literalmente "caca de vaca") o hachís de mala calidad. Sin embargo, mientras que *jaravaca* se quedó en ese ámbito, *guay* se extendió a todos los demás ámbitos. La palabra *jaravaca* apenas es conocida, pero [aparece registrada](https://atunara.com/atunatiki/tiki-index.php?page=Jaravaca) como de uso en la zona del estrecho de Gibraltar, concretamente en la wiki del barrio de La Atunara, en La Línea de la Concepción (también conocido como el barrio narco). En dicha web inciden en el origen árabe de *guay*.
- Que proceda de una zarzuela de 1861, que incluye el siguiente verso: "salero de buten guay". De hecho este verso se suele usar como origen también de la expresión "de buten" o, coloquialmente, "dabuten". Existe la posibilidad de que esta zarzuela, titulada *La cruz de los humeros: zarzuela en un acto y en verso*, se representara en Madrid a principios de los 80 (o antes) y se extrajera la expresión, añadiéndose al habla coloquial. Pero no encuentro en prensa anuncio alguno de dicha representación. A lo mejor a alguien que se conocía la zarzuela le dijeron "¡de buten!" y este respondió "¡guay!".

Estas son las opciones que veo más plausibles. Tal vez la del origen árabe asociado a la droga pueda tener más credibilidad, por el auge del consumo de estas sustancias que hubo precisamente en la década de 1980, coincidiendo con el auge de la palabra *guay*. El origen partiendo de *kwayyis* (he visto varias transcripciones posibles), pasando por Andalucía, perdiendo la *-s* y estableciéndose en *guay* es razonable, y las fechas cuadran.

Comment: @walen puede ser, o también puede ser esto: "¡Guay, guay, guay, guay, guay!, ladraron mil perros en diversos tonos." Esa frase es de un libro de 1977, y dada la frecuencia de uso de la palabra (muy baja) puede haber bastado para subir la gráfica. De hecho si se quita el "smoothing" de la gráfica, los picos son precisamente en 1973 y 1977, que se corresponderán con publicaciones de libros que usan mucho la palabra.

Comment: @Charlie en efecto, lo más probable es que no sepamos nunca el origen, pero tu respuesta es un resumen del estado de 'guay'; por cierto, no conocía la herramienta de Ngram Viewer, fantástica!

Comment: En la tragicomedia de "Calisto y Melibea" o "La Celestina" de Fernando de Rojas, ya aparece en sus diálogos. Editada en 1499. Diálogo: (174) ELICIA.- _Tres días ha que no me ves. ¡Nunca Dios te vea, nunca Dios te consuele ni visite! ¡Guay de la triste, que en ti tiene su esperança e el fin de todo su bien!_

Answer (score 0):

Proviene del árabe, pero no de kuais (que nada tiene que ver con lo que nos ocupa) si no de la palabra "wail", que se encuentra varias veces recogida en el Corán y cuyo significado es el mismo que recoge la acepción antigua de la palabra, ay. Suele usarse en frases tipo: "ay de aquellos que..."

De hecho en América Latina sigue usandose la palabra con este mismo significado.

Comment: La pregunta es sobre el origen de guay en el sentido de "muy bueno" o "muy bien". No sobre la palabra "guay" con el significado de "ay"

Comment: Es posible citar la "sura" del Coran en que la palabra "wail" se encuentra?